# Convert dictionary's array to array of dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

Is there any possible ways to convert the following structure into a given structure

**Input:-**

```
var dic : [String:Array<Int>] = [
    "array1": [1,1,1],
    "array2": [2,2,2],
    "array3": [3,3,3]
]
```

**Expected output:-**

```
var result = [
    [
        "array1" : 1,
        "array2" : 2,
        "array3" : 3
    ],[
        "array1" : 1,
        "array2" : 2,
        "array3" : 3
    ],[
        "array1" : 1,
        "array2" : 2,
        "array3" : 3
    ]
]
```

Comment: The structure of the array is showing an error. 
```
Unexpected token ':'
```
Please check!

Answer (score 0):

try this logic I hope it will work ... :)

```
var dic : [String:Array<Int>] = [
    "array1": [1,1,1],
    "array2": [2,2,2],
    "array3": [3,3,3]
]

var finalresult = Array<Any>()
var keys = Array(dic.keys)


for i in 0...dic["array1"]!.count-1{
   var arr2 = Array<Any>()
    for j in 0...keys.count-1{
        var arr1 = [String:Int]()

        arr1[keys[j]] = dic[keys[j]]![j]
        print(arr1)
        arr2.append(arr1)
    }
    print(arr2)
    finalresult.append(arr2)
}
print(finalresult)
```

the final result is your output. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two step solution, first create an empty collection structure and then fill it with the values

```
var converted: [[String: Int]] = []

for _ in 0..<dic.count {
    converted.append([:])
}

for (key, value) in dic {    
    for (index, number) in value.enumerated() {
        converted[index][key] = number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A single liner:

```
var dic : [String:Array<Int>] = [
    "array1": [1,1,1],
    "array2": [2,2,2],
    "array3": [3,3,3]
]

let result = dic.values.first!.indices.map {index in dic.mapValues {$0[index]} }
print(result)
//->[["array3": 3, "array2": 2, "array1": 1], ["array3": 3, "array2": 2, "array1": 1], ["array3": 3, "array2": 2, "array1": 1]]
```

Assuming:

- all values in `dic` has the same size
- `dic` has at least one entry